# Is there an API endpoint to see if a phone number is "in service" with our account

Tags: twilio-api

I'm new to the Twilio API. I'd like to verify whether a set of phone numbers is "in service" with our account. These are phone numbers like PN0c8XXXX...... and is there a way to send numbers in bulk to be sure that they are associated with our account and in working order? I see a call like this (would Sid be our PN0c8... number?):

```
GET https://verify.twilio.com/v2/Services/{Sid}
```

but not clear if this is what we want or if it supports batch mode. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by verifying a set of phone numbers in "in service" with your account.

However, you can check the details of a phone number in your account using the [Incoming Phone Numbers API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource). If you have a phone number SID, the ID that starts with `PN`, you can [fetch an individual phone number resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource#fetch-an-incomingphonenumber-resource) by making a request to:

```
https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{AccountSid}/IncomingPhoneNumbers/{PhoneNumberSid}.json
```

There isn't an API request that allows you to send multiple SIDs, but you can [list all your incoming phone numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/api/incomingphonenumber-resource#read-multiple-incomingphonenumber-resources) and then check against that list in your own code.

---

As an aside, the URL you asked about in the question is the [Twilio Verify API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify). Verify allows you to verify user's phone numbers over SMS or voice, and can also perform verification via TOTP, push notification or emails. It's meant for verification or two factor authentication.

Comment: how would we handle large amount of accounts? I see the `limit: 20` but our account has tens of thousands of numbers so that's not going to work very well. Any way to get a file download?

Comment: You can raise the limit of numbers you list to 1,000 per request and then paginate through. If you want an export of the data beyond doing that, your best bet is to ask Twilio support.